# get values from multidimensional array with objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, mt940

I've used a little script for importing mt940 files (file of dutch bank transactions).

This is the array I get back but I need a little bit help to get the right values out of the array.

```
Array (
    [0] => Statement_banking Object (
        [_bank:Statement_banking:private] => ING
        [_account:Statement_banking:private] => 111111111
        [_transactions:Statement_banking:private] => Array (
            [0] => Transaction_banking Object (
                [account:Transaction_banking:private] => 111111111
                [accountName:Transaction_banking:private] => V. DE JONG KERKSTRAAT 1154 1234 BW
                [price:Transaction_banking:private] => 0.56
                [debitcredit:Transaction_banking:private] => C
                [description:Transaction_banking:private] => 0111111111 V. DE JONG KERKSTRAAT 1154 1234 BW ENSCHEDE BET.KENM. 1004510036716378 3305330802 AFLOSSINGSTERMIJN 188616 / 1E TERMIJN
                [valueTimestamp:Transaction_banking:private] => 1279749600
                [entryTimestamp:Transaction_banking:private] => 1279749600
                [transactionCode:Transaction_banking:private] => 078
            )
            [1] => Transaction_banking Object (
                [account:Transaction_banking:private] => 111111111 
                [accountName:Transaction_banking:private] => CUSTOMER NL SPOEDBETALING 
                [price:Transaction_banking:private] => 10.45 
                [debitcredit:Transaction_banking:private] => C 
                [description:Transaction_banking:private] => 0111111111 CUSTOMER NL SPOEDBETALING GE2009120212345 RE091202Â­3737 /RFB/NLÂ­FMIÂ­021209 NLÂ­FMIÂ­021209 VOORSCHOT COMMISSIE
                [valueTimestamp:Transaction_banking:private] => 1279749600 
                [entryTimestamp:Transaction_banking:private] => 1279749600 
                [transactionCode:Transaction_banking:private] => 077
            )
            [2] => Transaction_banking Object (
                [account:Transaction_banking:private] => 
                [accountName:Transaction_banking:private] => 
                [price:Transaction_banking:private] => 10000.99 
                [debitcredit:Transaction_banking:private] => D 
                [description:Transaction_banking:private] => VERZAMELBETALING BATCHÂ­ID: 012345 TOTAAL 198 POSTEN 
                [valueTimestamp:Transaction_banking:private] => 1279749600 
                [entryTimestamp:Transaction_banking:private] => 1279749600 
                [transactionCode:Transaction_banking:private] => 029 ) )
                [_startPrice:Statement_banking:private] => 44 
                [_endPrice:Statement_banking:private] => 9945 
                [_timestamp:Statement_banking:private] => 1279749600 
                [_number:Statement_banking:private] => 100
            )
        )
```

This key for example gives me the name and the address:

```
[accountName:Transaction_banking:private] => V. DE JONG KERKSTRAAT 1154 1234 BW
```

This key gives me the transaction price:

```
[price:Transaction_banking:private] => 0.56
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Those are private properties of `Transaction_banking` and `Statement_banking` classes. What do the classes look like? There probably is a method for retrieving the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would access the address and transaction price as:

```
foreach( $yourArray[0]->_transactions as $transaction ) {
    $foo = $transaction->accountName;
    $bar = $transaction->price;
}
```

But in this particular case, some of your fields are private, meaning that you can't access their value directly. You could try defining your own `Statement_banking` and `Transaction_banking` classes and define accessor methods for those fields, such as:

```
public class Statement_banking {
    public function getTransactions() {
        return $this->_transactions;
    }
}

public class Transaction_banking {
    public function getAccountName() {
        return $this->accountName;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }
}
```

Then your loop code becomes this:

```
foreach( $yourArray[0]->getTransactions() as $transaction ) {
    $foo = $transaction->getAccountName();
    $bar = $transaction->getPrice();
}
```

If you want to iterate over the outer array as well, you can expand it to:

```
foreach( $yourArray as $statement ) {
    foreach( $statement->getTransactions() as $transaction ) {
        $foo = $transaction->getAccountName();
        $bar = $transaction->getPrice();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Logically You need to use nested foreach or for loop, Not sure about syntax but below PHP code may help you and then you may convert in required language

```
  $outputArr = Is your array.
  foreach ( $outputArr as $firstchild){
   forach ( $firstchild as $key => $secondchildvalue){
     // $key is basically your key value [price:Transaction_banking:private]
     // $secondchildvalue is your info value 0.56
   }
  }
```

Comment: This won't work. They are private properties, `price:Transaction_banking:private` is not the key. The whole point of them being private is so you can't directly access them outside the class.